# Is using Mono<Optional<T>> discouraged?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am writing a web server with extensive usage of reactive programming. I noticed that I forgot to check if `Mono` is empty too many times. I am using WebFlux, so it converts an empty `Mono` to a `200 OK` response, and it makes it very hard to detect these errors.

One way of reducing these mistakes is to make absence of a value explicit by using `Mono<Optional<T>>` instead of `Mono.empty()`.

This feels very similar to `Optional` and `null` debate, it even uses the same class. And while there are many people that are in favour of using `Optional` and it is widely supported by libraries, I've yet to see anyone using `Mono<Optional<T>>`.

Are there any drawbacks of using `Mono<Optional<T>>`?

What is a better way to reliably handle cases of absent values?

Comment: It looks like `Optional<Optional<T>>` :)

Answer (score 4):

By using `Mono<Optional<T>>` instead of `Mono<T>`, you're putting yourself into a tricky situation of receiving an empty `Mono`, but assuming that it will always have an instance of `Optional`, so it doesn't really help, and only adds an unnecessary allocation.

There is a handy operator [Mono#single](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#single--), it will throw and error if you expected a non-empty `Mono`, but got an empty one instead.